# Removing common elements from a dictionary of lists in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of lists and the lists contain dictionaries like so:

```
my_dict = {
'list1': [{'catch': 100, 'id': '1'}, {'catch': 101, 'id': '2'}, 
          {'catch': 50, 'id': '1'}], 
'list2': [{'catch': 189, 'id': '1'}, {'catch': 120, 'id': '12'}], 
'list3': [{'catch': 140, 'id': '1'}, {'catch': 10, 'id': '100'}]
}
```

What is the most *pythonic* way of removing the list items with commin 'id' values and storing them in a separate list? So the output would be something like this:

```
my_dict = {
'list1': [{'catch': 101, 'id': '2'}], 
'list2': [{'catch': 120, 'id': '12'}], 
'list3': [ {'catch': 10, 'id': '100'}],
'list4': [{'catch': 100, 'id': '1'}, , {'catch': 50, 'id': '1'}, 
          {'catch': 189, 'id': '1'}, {'catch': 140, 'id': '1'}]
}
```

In my program I have 7 lists similar to this, and if an 'id' appears in two or more of these lists, I want to store all appearances of an item with that 'id' in the 8th list for further processing

with regards, 
finnurtorfa

Comment: Perhaps it's time to rethink your data structure instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters while I completely agree - A real life example of when this would happen would be a list of objects returned from a document based database...

Comment: What's the point of the dict keys? I'm ignoring them in my answer because it seems that they don't actually mean anything, but perhaps they do...

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree, after seeing the answers here, I am going to rethink my data structure :)

Comment: @katrielalex Thanks for the answer. It's not exactly what I had in mind, but I am going to rethink my datastructure and  will use something similar to your answer

Answer (score 3):

Consider restructuring your data into something like this:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> { k: [d['catch'] for d in v] for k, v in itertools.groupby(sorted(itertools.chain(*my_dict.itervalues()), key=lambda d: d['id']), lambda d: d['id']) }
{'1': [100, 50, 140, 189], '2': [101], '100': [10], '12': [120]}
```

You haven't described what your data represents, so this may not be appropriate for you. But the tools used (`chain` and `groupby` from `itertools`) should at least give you some ideas.

Edit: I used the sample answer from the question in my testing by accident. Fixed by adding sorting to the input to `groupby`.

Comment: Agreed. All the data really is is a collection of (`id, catch`) pairs, which you can store as a dictionary of `id: [catch]`.

Comment: You probably want to use `chain.from_iterable` so you can iterate over the values lazily.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> get_id = operator.itemgetter("id")
>>> flattened_dict = itertools.chain.from_iterable(my_dict.values())
>>> groups = itertools.groupby(sorted(flattened_dict, key=get_id), get_id)
>>> {k: list(v) for k, v in groups}
{'1': [{'catch': 100, 'id': '1'},
  {'catch': 50, 'id': '1'},
  {'catch': 140, 'id': '1'},
  {'catch': 189, 'id': '1'}],
 '100': [{'catch': 10, 'id': '100'}],
 '12': [{'catch': 120, 'id': '12'}],
 '2': [{'catch': 101, 'id': '2'}]}
```

Explanation:

- `get_id` is a function that takes an object `x` and returns `x["id"]`.
- `flattened_dict` is just an iterable over all the lists (i.e. concatenating all the `.values()` of `my_dict`
- Now we sort `flattened_dict` with the key function `get_id` -- that is, sort by ID -- and group the result by id.

This basically works because `itertools.groupby` is awesome.

Comment: question for you: how do you keep code golfing that answer if you try to fulfill OP's need to remove common elements from existing lists and put them into additional ones ? In your solution, list1 2 3 are renumbered.

Comment: I wouldn't call this code golfing. I'd call it 'using the powerful tools that Python gives you for free'.

Comment: And to answer your questions, that would be a bit of a pain, but perfectly doable -- but as I'm not clear what the OP exactly wants, I'm hesitant to make up requirements to write nasty code.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the following line:

```
my_dict = {
'list1': [{'catch': 100, 'id': '1'}, {'catch': 101, 'id': '2'}, 
      {'catch': 50, 'id': '1'}], 
'list2': [{'catch': 189, 'id': '1'}, {'catch': 120, 'id': '12'}], 
'list3': [{'catch': 140, 'id': '1'}, {'catch': 10, 'id': '100'}]
}

from itertools import groupby

sub = {}
for k in my_dict:
 for kk, g in groupby( my_dict[k], lambda v: v["id"] ):
   if not kk in sub:
    sub[kk] = []
   sub[kk] = sub[kk] + list( g )

print sub

{'1': [{'catch': 100, 'id': '1'}, {'catch': 50, 'id': '1'}, {'catch': 140, 'id': '1'}, {'catch': 189, 'id': '1'}], '12': [{'catch': 120, 'id': '12'}], '100': [{'catch': 10, 'id': '100'}], '2': [{'catch': 101, 'id': '2'}]}
```